# Why is this a valid comparison

Tags: c#

Here is some example code:

```
static DateTime time;
if (time == null)
{
/* do something */
}
```

Since `DateTime` cannot be null, why does this code compile?

**Edit:**
The issue is not just that this code will always return false,but why something like `DateTime` which is **never** null is allowed in such a comparison.

Comment: I believe it's because there's an implicit conversion from `DateTime` to `DateTime?`. However, this conversion isn't checked consistently...

Comment: (Or at least wasn't checked consistently... I'm sure there used to be some oddities around it, but I can't reproduce them with Roslyn.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although `time` is of a non-nullable value type, it can be converted to nullable and compared to `null`. The comparison would yield `false`, which is a valid outcome.

This does not mean, however, that it is a good code. Tools, such as re:sharper, would flag this line with a warning saying "Expression is always false".

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 displays a warning for some, but not all value types. For example, if you had used `int` instead of `DateTime`,  you'd get a green squiggly line (warning) "expression is always false"; with `DateTime` you don't get such a warning.